# detect URL changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know this question has been asked before, and I've actually found a few solutions that I've implemented. Unfortunately, I couldn't get what I wanted.

I haven't done AngularJS before, and what I am trying to do is:

1. Detect when the URL changes
2. Do some processing depending on what the URL changed to

2nd part is pretty much done. I have a function to call when the URL changes. Let's call it **myFunction()**.

The **html** element of the site has 2 attributes: **ng-controller** and **ng-app**.

*ng-controller*: myCtrl

*ng-app*: myApp

I have a JavaScript file loaded at the **head** element. What I ultimately want to do is to add some logic in that file to watch for URL changes.

The last thing I've tried in Firebug was:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $location, $rootScope, $log) {
  $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
    $log.info("location changing to:" + next);
  });
});
```

However, this does not log anything on URL change.

Comment: Are these full page refreshes?

Comment: @Chandermani Yes, looks like it.

Comment: The above location tracking code would work only if the controller is already loaded when the location change happens. For full page refresh these events do not work.

Answer (score 1):

[`$locationChangeStart`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#$locationChangeStart) event is only available on `$rootScope.Scope` (basically `$scope`).

So you should be using `$scope` instead of `$rootScope`

```
$scope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
  $log.info("location changing to:" + next);
});
```

And for `$rootScope` the available event is [`$routeChangeStart`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#$routeChangeStart) which should be using inside `run` method block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$routeChangeSuccess` event.

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
       myFunction(); 
    }
});
```

Get information about the current route you can with `$route.current` object. For its use, don't forget to inject `$route` in your controller.